# Creating an element with properties, using an object-literal

Tags: jquery, dom

Since version 1.4 of jQuery; you have been able to create an element using an object literal, defining the elements properties...

```
$("<div />",
{
    id: "test",
    name: "test",
    class: "test-class"
});
```

On top of assigning a few properties to an element; I'd like to add some in-line styles. Is this possible, using the object literal?... I'm thingking something along the lines of:

```
$("<div />",
{
    id: "test",
    name: "test",
    class: "test-class",
    style: {
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        background-color: "#fff"
    }
});
```

Comment: I know this is beyond the point of the question, but I think `className` is required instead of `class` since `class` is a reserved word.

Comment: @patrick - +1 - you're correct I tend to forget it's IE specifically that doesn't like it, it needs quotes or className

Comment: @patrick: wrapping class in a string would work too, e.g. `"class": "test-class"`.  jQuery expects anything that would work with *attr()* function, so it's synonymous with *attr("class", "...")*.

Comment: @Andy E - True. It's a javascript issue, not a jQuery issue. I forgot about the possibility of making it a string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass method names and arguments to the map that will be executed on the object.

```
$("<div />",
{
    id: "test",
    name: "test",
    class: "test-class",
    css: {
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
    }
});
```

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> Furthermore, any event type can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: val, **css**, html, text, data, width, height, or offset.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `style` use `css`, like this:

```
$("<div />", {
    id: "test",
    name: "test",
    "class": "test-class", //patrick's right, IE specifically doesn't like class
    css: {
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        "background-color": "#fff"
    }
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5KhVH/), also note that `background-color` (since it has a dash) needs to be in quotes, or be `backgroundColor`.  Other special properties are mapped this way, `val`, `css`, `html`, `text`, `data`, `width`, `height` and `offset` [are treated special here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L233).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (in a separate answer to make it possible to vote either of my solutions up or down separately) would be to just add a call to `.css()` afterwards:

```
$('<div>',
{
    id: 'test',
    name: 'test',
    class: 'test-class'
}).css(
{
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always write your own helper method that would let you do

```
$('<div>',
{
    id: 'test',
    name: 'test',
    class: 'test-class',
    style: $.objectToCss(
    {
        width: '100px',
        height: '100px',
        background-color: '#fff'
    })
}
```

An *entirely untested* version of such a helper method might look something like this:

```
$.objectToCss = function(obj) {
    var css;
    $.each(obj, function(name, value) {
        css += name + ': ' + value + ';';
    });
    return css;
};
```